# Parsing single user input string for advanced search criteria

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, pattern-matching, xregexp

I'm working on a custom search feature for a blog I'm coding from scratch. This blog is geared towards the technically inclined readers, and I wanted to allow readers to search through articles by defining some advanced search criteria in the search field (as opposed to having multiple search inputs, one for *title*, one for *tags*, one for *category*.. etc). Somewhat similar to Jiras [advanced search](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-764478330.html) or Googles [search operators](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html).

I will be coding this in Javascript, but Ill be using the **[xRegExp](http://xregexp.com/)** library, which supports all the cool features that the native RegExp doesnt (named group matching, look ahead, look behind, etc)

The "fields" that are searchable would be:

- Title
- Summary
- Author
- Category
- Tags
- Created (date)
- Updated (date)
- *(No field specified)* General search phrase

To add a search *"field"* to the search criteria, you would just type one of the fields names above, then a colon (`:`), then the search phrase associated to that field.

In addition to that, I would like to allow the viewer to add some "**OR**" and "**AND**" logic to the search criteria, such as searching for articles with the author *john.doe* **OR** *mike.smith*, or articles with the tags *bash* **AND** *scripting*. The **OR** operator could be `||`, and the **AND** operator could be `&&`.

Some example search strings:

> *author*:**linus** *tag*:**linux** **How Linux got started**

- *Author*: **Linus**
- *Tag*: **Linux**
- General search phrase: **How Linux got started**

> *author*:**john.doe**||**jane.smith** *categories*:**infosec**||**linux** *tags*:**linux**&&**security** **Securing your first Linux server**

- *Authors*: **john.doe** *OR* **jane.smith**
- *Categories*: **Infosec** *OR* **Linux**
- *Tags*: **Linux** *OR* **Security**
- General search phrase: **Securing your first Linux server**

### The Question

I was hoping to get as much of the string parsing done via Regex as I could. I got a little something going on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/w6rSa7/2), but im having a problem with matching for a pattern multiple times, separated by spaces.. So any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ps. sorry I didn't use your lib. I ussually only fall back to libs if I really need to. Didn't read your message well enough. Other than that I think the code is readable/easy to edit (unlike most regexp's).

I saw the nodejs tag as well, if you are using this to 'send' you can easily translate the pairs to key/values like this:

```
const pairSeperator = ':';
const valueSeperators = [
  { splitter: '||', replacingValue: 'OR' },
  { splitter: '&&', replacingValue: 'AND' },
];

const validKeyNames = [
  'title',
  'summary',
  'author',
  'category',
  'tag',
  'created',
  'updated',
];

function isValidKeyValuePair(input) {
  const possiblePair = input.split(pairSeperator);

  if (possiblePair.length == 2) {
    return validKeyNames.indexOf(possiblePair[0]) > -1;
  }

  return false;
}

function parseValue(value) {
  const valueSeperator = valueSeperators.find((s) => value.indexOf(s.splitter) > -1);
  if (valueSeperator) {
    return value
      .split(valueSeperator.splitter)
      .join(` ${valueSeperator.replacingValue} `);
  }

  return value;
}

function pairReduce(memo, strPair) {
  const [key, value] = strPair.split(pairSeperator);

  obj[key] = parseValue(value);
  return obj;
}


// this is function which handles your searchTerm
function parseSearch(searchTerm) {
  const splittedSearchTerm = searchTerm.split(' ');

  const filters = splittedSearchTerm
    .filter(isValidKeyValuePair)
    .reduce(pairReduce, {});

  const searchTerm = splittedSearchTerm
    .filter(input => !isKeyValuePair(input))
    .join(' ');

  return Object.assign(filters, { searchTerm });
  // input: parseSearch("tag:linux why Linux rocks?");
  // output: { "tag": "linux", "searchTerm": "why Linux rocks?" }
}
```

Comment: This approach pretty much offloads the entire thing onto the code, as opposed to using Regex. If I have a hard time getting the regex working, then I'll definitely end up using this. Thank you though!